# actitvity to another in Corona sdk

Tags: android, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am new to corona. I wanted to know how to create a new android activity in corona like in eclipse I used

```
Intent i= new Intent(this,new.class);
startActivity(i);
```

How do we do this in corona ? so that when i press back button, I go back to previous screen and so that the new activity is a new screen altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use storyboard for corona to go to another scene which is Intent going to another Activity in android and for handling back button for android device refer to this [link](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/34839-global-handling-of-android-hardware-back-button/)
for storyboard please refer to this [link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/)

Comment: could you give me an easy to understand link on storyboard?

Comment: i just edit my answer with link to the storyboard API just try to understand it because it will take too long for me to explain it